# DeviceGray colorspace always present even though xcolor cmyk option is being used

Tags: color, pdf, cmyk

Can someone explain why the `DeviceGray` colorspace model is always present in the output even though `xcolor` `cmyk` option is being used?

I ran the PDF analysis using this online tool: https://www.setasign.com/products/setapdf-core/demos/get-colors-from-pdf-with-php/

```
% !TEX program = xelatex

\documentclass{article}

% [xetex,cmyk] => DeviceCMYK, DeviceGray
% [xetex] => DeviceGray
\usepackage[xetex,cmyk]{xcolor}

\begin{document}
  test
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Color commands push a color on a stack and at the end of the group restore the previous color from it.

The default color on the stack is black, and so in the outer group you get this when you pop the color:

```
\RequirePackage{l3pdf}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\pdf_uncompress:
\ExplSyntaxOff

\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
%\special{color push cmyk 0 0 0 1}
\special{color push cmyk 0 0 1 1}
test
\special{color pop}

\end{document}
```

This gives (a bit shortened and commented:):

```
0 0 1 1 K 0 0 1 1 k %<-- push color
BT /F1 9.9626 Tf 76.712 -62.765 Td[<0069003200620069>]TJ ET 
0 G 0 g %<-- pop color
```

You can avoid this by pushing first a different color on the stack. If you uncomment the first special you get:

```
0 0 0 1 K 0 0 0 1 k 
0 0 1 1 K 0 0 1 1 k 
BT /F1 9.9626 Tf 76.712 -62.765 Td[<0069003200620069>]TJ ET 
0 0 0 1 K 0 0 0 1 k
```

Comment: Thanks. Master as always! Can we say that the `black` (belonging to `DeviceGray`) was "defined and present on the color stack *but not used for any object* in my MWE"?

Comment: `0 G 0 g ` is in your stream as it is in mine, so it is used.

Comment: This is what I actually meant: *nothing was rendered with that color*.